# Oracle SQL Validate 2 fields against Junction table and flag

Tags: sql, oracle

I've taken over a oracle DB which is a bit of a mess.

There is a data table, which collect various data sets. However 2  of the fields were put as free sections with no validation against each one.

I'm planning to make this a joint drop-down from data from a junction table to collect correct combinations that are allowed.  But first I need  the flag the incorrect information, so I can forward this on to be changed. using oracle. how do I validated the 2 tables against each other and flag. I think its some joins and case but just can not figure this one out.

I need to show the relevant junction ID and err in not in the junction table. Please example below. All help will be welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some thing like -

```
SELECT D.Job_date,
       D.acc,
       D.task,
       NVL (to_Char(J.a_t_id), 'err') AS Junc_tbl_id
  FROM DATA_TBL D
       LEFT JOIN Junc_tbl J ON D.acc = J.acc AND D.task = J.task;
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d6ad/7/0).

Comment: I think you can't use NVL to convert a number to a string. Not sure though.